# VS Code unit test checkmarks in the editor do not show up

Tags: python, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-code

I am new to VS Code and I run unittest in VS Code for Python.
The checkmarks are for each method is shown only inside the beaker button but not inside the code editor.

[image]

I follow the steps below but nothing shows up inside the text editor.

To test your classes use the keyboard shortcut "Ctrl + shift + P" for windows or "cmd+shift+P" on Mac to bring up the command Palette.
Enter "Python: Configure Tests" and select unittest. You will then be prompted to select the directory of where your tests are located and finally you need to
choose "test_*.py" option because your file names should have the form test_.py

This will allow you to individually test methods without having to wait for all of them to be tested.
To test all methods and to view coverage do the following.

1. python  will run your test file and tell you how many passed

Comment: After you have configured the test of unittest, you still can not find the green triangle of the test method in the code editor, and after you run the test method in the test panel, you still can not get the result of the test method in the code editor? Does mean, you can not get anything in the unittest file in the editor? And could you have a look at this [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-visual-studio-code-september-2021-release/)?

Comment: I can not reproduce it of unittest, but the pytest really acts as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Try to close and reopen your test file (`./tests/test_*.py`).